# Get ALL IP addresses that contains X hostname in LAN (Multiple same hostnames)

Tags: c#, asp.net, network-programming, ip-address, hostname

I'm trying to loop through all IP address within range (192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.255) and print out the IP address that contains X hostname.

I am trying to use this code, but it only give me the last IP address which contains X hostname, but there are multiple IP addresses with this hostname:

```
string customPc = "myCustomPc";
            IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry(customPc);

            foreach (IPAddress theaddress in host.AddressList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(theaddress.ToString());
            }
```

also, I am trying to do it this way, but it prints out the same result - the last IP address that has this hostname:

```
string host = "myCustomPc";
                IPHostEntry hostEntry;

                hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(host); 

                if (hostEntry.AddressList.Length > 0)
                {
                    var ip = hostEntry.AddressList[0];
                    Console.WriteLine(ip + ": Your custom PC is found!");
                }`
```

Answer (score 0):

Is you problem that you're printing only one element from the AddressList collection?

Try this:

```
foreach(var a in hostEntry.AddressList) {
  Console.WriteLine(a + ": Your custom PC is found!");
}
```

or use [Dns.GetHostAddresses(String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.dns.gethostaddresses?view=net-5.0)

```
foreach(var a in Dns.GetHostAddresses(host)) {
  Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

---

> how can I loop from 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.255

Here's one way

```
for(int d = 1; d <=255; d++)
{
   var ipstr = $"192.161.1.{d}";
}
```

Comment: I tried it, it gives me only one IP address, but there are around 7-10 computers in my LAN with the same HostName